# Why does the Ruby splat not work for array coercion in conditional assignment?

Tags: ruby

Although the splat (`*`) construct is commonly referred to as the splat *operator*, it is clear that it is a different beast, compared to other unary operators like the negation (`!`) operator.

The splat works fine on it's own (i.e. not wrapped in brackets) when used in assignment (`=`), but produces an error when used with conditional assignment (`||=`). Example:

```
a = *(1..3)
#=> [1, 2, 3]

b ||= *(1..3)
SyntaxError: (irb):65: syntax error, unexpected *
```

I am not looking for alternative ways of doing the same thing, but looking for someone with a better understanding of the Ruby internals to explain why this usage of the splat construct works in the first case but not in the second.

Comment: My guess would be this is just an imperfection of ruby parser.

Comment: My best guess is that `a = *(1..3)` is actually parsed more like `a =* (1..3)` so `=*` is a bit like an operator and `||=*` would be handled like a different non-existent operator.

Comment: @amoebe Indeed! An explicit `a =* a || (1..3)` works.

Comment: Fun thing about the splat - `*a = (1..3)` will also change the value of `a` to `[1,2,3]` even though it is on the left. `*a ||= 1..3` still doesn't work though.

Comment: @PSkocik But keep in mind that `||=` does avoid name errors when the variable is undefined and [other funny stuff](http://www.rubyinside.com/what-rubys-double-pipe-or-equals-really-does-5488.html).

Comment: The implementation seems to be somewhere between https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/parse.y and https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/node.c. Would be awesome if somebody could explain the logic.

Answer (score 8):

Here's my understanding of the practical goal of splat. This is for Ruby 2.2 MRI/KRI/YARV.

Ruby splat destructures an object into an array during assignment.

These examples all provide the same result, when `a` is falsey:

```
a = *(1..3)
a = * (1..3)
a =* (1..3)
a = *1..3
a = * 1..3
a = * a || (1..3)
a = * [1, 2, 3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
```

The splat does the destructuring during the assigment, as if you wrote this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
```

(Note: the splat calls `#to_a`. This means that when you splat an array, there's no change. This also means that you can define your own kinds of destructuring for any class of your own, if you wish.)

But these statements fail:

```
*(1..3)
* 1..3
* [1,2,3]
false || *(1..3)
x = x ? x : *(1..3) 
=> SyntaxError
```

These statements fail because there's no assignment happening exactly when the splat occurs.

Your question is this special case:

```
b ||= *(1..3)
```

Ruby expands this to:

```
b = b || *(1..3)
```

This statement fails because there's no assignment happening exactly when the splat occurs.

If you need to solve this in your own code, you can use a temp var, such as:

```
b ||= (x=*(1..3))
```

Worth mentioning: there's an entirely different use of splat when it's on the left hand side of the expression. This splat is a low-priority greedy collector during parallel assignment.

Examples:

```
*a, b = [1, 2, 3]  #=> a is [1, 2], b is 3
a, *b = [1, 2, 3]  #=> a is 1, b is [2, 3]
```

So this does parse:

```
*a = (1..3)  #=> a is (1..3)
```

It sets `a` to all the results on the right hand side, i.e. the range.

In the rare case that the splat can be understood as either a destructurer or a collector, then the destructurer has precendence.

This line:

```
x = * y = (1..3)
```

Evaluates to this:

```
x = *(y = (1..3))
```

Not this:

```
x = (*y = (1..3))
```

Comment: Massive +1. Awesome answer.

Comment: @fylooi I added more detail for you.

Comment: @joelparkerhenderson: Do I understand it correctly, then, that this behaviour of the splat is intimately tied to the assignment operator (probably on a much lower level of the language?)

Comment: Just remembered another not very explicable use case for splat - `[*input]` - If `input` is an array, returns `input`, otherwise returns `[input]`. Interesting part is that this one happens without an assignment.

Comment: @joelparkerhenderson You are wrong, splat doesn't return an array, try `p *[1,2]` vs `p [1,2]`, it returns all elements of the array sequentially. And then ruby converts it as an [implicit array assignment](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ca6b174078fa15f33655be704d9409fdbc4f9929/doc/syntax/assignment.rdoc#implicit-array-assignment)

Comment: @Evgeny I was responing to @fylooi, who was asking about splat without assignment. (You're correct, that if there *is* an assignment, such as an implicit assignment, splate behaves differently). As far as i know, without assigniment e.g. merely `*array` what happens is splat calls #to_a, and Array returns `self`. Try it by monkey-patching it, such as `class Array; def to_a; raise;  end; end`. On my system, `*[1,2,3]` raises.

Comment: @fylooi To your point of splat without assigment on an array: splat without assigment merely calls #to_a, which Array defines as returning self. So splatting an array without assignment doesn't do anything. (Also see Evgney's comment about splat *with* assigment e.g. implicit assignemtn)

Comment: @joelparkerhenderson interesting thing, just thought maybe it calls `#to_a` because eigenclass was changed when you redefined the method, and `RB_TYPE_P`(link in my answer) returns false... will try to find it out later...

Comment: @joelparkerhenderson it's the irb raising this, [backtrace](http://pastebin.com/wYDnn9SZ), not ruby. And it will raise even if you simply call Array.class there... without any splat. Can't make it raise with a ruby program.

Comment: Very interesting, and you make great points. You're right, I see different behavior within a ruby program than within IRB. I'll update my answer. Ideally someone with more experience will be able to explain what the spec is.

Answer (score 0):

By splatting `*(1..3)` in your expression you get `1, 2, 3`, and when it is assigned it behaves like mass assignment, but ruby seems not to support it for conditional assignment.
 I.e. `a=1,2,3` is just a syntax sugar of ruby. Just use an array explicitly:

```
a ||= [*1..3] #=> [1, 2, 3]
```

And actually you only use part of splat functionality here - it's [autoconversion to array](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/4208d09b1a99885b7be6fe6b215ea7798c4f297f/vm_insnhelper.c#L813) :) so you can simply do:

```
a ||= (1..3).to_a #=> [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I think they do not add mass conditional assignment to keep code easy to understand, if you write `a,b ||= 1,2` it's unclear if ruby should assign only one argument if the other is not nil or just left them unchanged...